# Can a 0800 and 00800 be from different companies in UK

Tags: authentication, phishing, phone

I recently received a call from a 00800 number, that seemed like a prerecorded message asking me to press some keys to continue. I disconnected.

I later googled the number and I noticed that a company in UK (Thames Water) uses the same number but with 0800. When calling the 0800 version I could hear different 'automatic secretary'.

Is it possible that 00800 is controlled by a different company than the 0800 number? If so, then this is a dangerous scamming technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`00` is the telephone prefix to dial international numbers in many countries, including the UK. The 1 to 3 digits that follow 00 are a [country calling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), in this case the code is `800` which is an [international toll-free number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toll-free_telephone_number#Universal_International_Freephone_Service).

As far as I know, 00800 numbers are always toll-free, so this can't be a scam where you are tricked into calling an expensive number.

The 00800xxx number bears no relation with the UK number 0800xxx. So this may be a scam where you're tricked into communicating with a party you aren't expecting. For example, they might try to trick you into paying them something, pretending to be Thames Water giving you the last chance to pay your water bill before they cut you off. Or it could be a different scam copying an 800 number from a different country such as the US. Or it could be some simple spam, perhaps with an invalid caller ID. Or it could be a mistake.

Comment: That clarifies- it also turned out to be a mistake, after clarifying with Thames Water (not a scam).